# Advanced tinyMCE insert link error

Tags: tinymce

My wordpress website has been installed advanced tinymce plugin. In editor, I click insert link and type some characters and then it suggests me link to pages and posts. The first link is inserted successfully but the second one is removed link and keep only the plain text when I click save. I try to view source code before saving, the second link has this html tag

```
<span id="_mce_caret" data-mce-bogus="1"><a data-mce-href="mylink" href="mylink">mylink</a></span>
```

and the first one does not have this. Please help me.